# li jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery

Please, someone can help me? I can't resize #top from li menu item. this is html code:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="topheader"></div>
<div id="baseheader">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="260" height="131" /></div>
<div id="contentmenu"><div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li id="nav1"><a href="#">ESTUDIO</a></li>
<li id="nav2"><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li id="nav3"><a href="#">SERVICIOS</a></li>
<li id="nav4"><a href="#">PRESUPUESTO</a></li>
<li id="nav5"><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

AND THIS jQUERY

```
$("#nav li[id='nav4']").live('click', function(e) {
$("#top").animate({height:114});
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/z4KrL/

Comment: What do you mean by "resize" #top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated"

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#nav").on('click', '#nav4', function () {
    $("#top").animate({height:114});
     return false;
   });
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4KrL/9/

and don't use so menu ID's use Classes, [e.g](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

UPDATE:

- copy code from above to the bottom of the page
- Add link to the Jquery library `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- remove link to external `topheight.js`

Comment: Why should we not use IDs? They're pretty useful...

Comment: That article does not argue against using ids.

Comment: pasted wrong link, sorry, http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: That article does not argue against using ids either.

Comment: I can just imagine css styling with html like that

Comment: thanks, bt #top don't make nothing. not working. another solution?

Comment: it's works, see here http://jsfiddle.net/z4KrL/17/, click on the "PRESUPUESTO"

Comment: you can see it here please. Don´t work. You can see it something wrong?

http://www.vektorlab.com/nuevo/prueba.html

Comment: I don't see link to Jquery library in your page?

Comment: ?¿ sorry, i don't understand. your code from jsfiddle.net/z4KrL/17 don't work on local. why? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: yes, sorry, one moment...

Comment: now you can see it. many thanks for helping

http://www.vektorlab.com/nuevo/prueba.html

Comment: Ok, now work it!! but why i can't put the code in external .js?